# how to get specific data from a txt file in c++

Tags: c++, txt

it's my frist publication and i have a question-
I have a .txt file that I want to separate by the ",".
Example:
example1,example2,example3,example4
I want to get example1 and store in an array and so on for example2 , example3, example4.
string[0] = example1
string[1] = example2
etc....

Answer (score 0):

getline by default will split input by end-line chatracter, but can do for any character, including ',' - see example (using a stringstream):

```cpp
std::string input = "word1,word2,word3";
std::stringstream sstream(input);

std::string word;
while(std::getline(sstream, word, ',')) {
    std::cout << word << '\n';
}
```